# Issue:Deploying a Model using Azure Machine Learning Service

Tags: python, docker, anaconda, conda

I created a classifier model using Azure Machine Learning service, after successfully registering a model I built the correct environment for container instance Unfortunately when I am deploying my solution it's giving me the error:

```
Creating image
Running............................................
Failed
ERROR - Image creation polling reached non-successful terminal state, current state: Failed
Error response from server:
StatusCode: 400
Message: Docker image build failed.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
WebserviceException                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-aa6e81eea9f4> in <module>
     14                               workspace = ws)
     15 
---> 16 image.wait_for_creation(show_output = True)

~/anaconda3_501/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/core/image/image.py in wait_for_creation(self, show_output)
    426                                       'current state: {}\n'
    427                                       'Error response from server:\n'
--> 428                                       '{}'.format(self.creation_state, error_response), logger=module_logger)
    429 
    430         print('Image creation operation finished for image {}, operation "{}"'.format(self.id, operation_state))

WebserviceException: WebserviceException:
    Message: Image creation polling reached non-successful terminal state, current state: Failed
Error response from server:
StatusCode: 400
Message: Docker image build failed.
    InnerException None
    ErrorResponse 
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Image creation polling reached non-successful terminal state, current state: Failed\nError response from server:\nStatusCode: 400\nMessage: Docker image build failed."
    }
}
```

however here is my deployment build logs to get more details:

```
2020/02/19 12:31:54 Downloading source code...
2020/02/19 12:31:55 Finished downloading source code
2020/02/19 12:31:56 Creating Docker network: acb_default_network, driver: 'bridge'
2020/02/19 12:31:56 Successfully set up Docker network: acb_default_network
2020/02/19 12:31:56 Setting up Docker configuration...
2020/02/19 12:31:57 Successfully set up Docker configuration
2020/02/19 12:31:57 Logging in to registry: kspml849c70e2.azurecr.io
2020/02/19 12:31:58 Successfully logged into kspml849c70e2.azurecr.io
2020/02/19 12:31:58 Executing step ID: acb_step_0. Timeout(sec): 5400, Working directory: '', Network: 'acb_default_network'
2020/02/19 12:31:58 Scanning for dependencies...
2020/02/19 12:31:59 Successfully scanned dependencies
2020/02/19 12:31:59 Launching container with name: acb_step_0
Sending build context to Docker daemon  60.93kB
Step 1/15 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/base:intelmpi2018.3-ubuntu16.04@sha256:a1b514f3ba884b9a7695cbba5638933ddaf222e8ce3e8c81e8cdf861679abb05
sha256:a1b514f3ba884b9a7695cbba5638933ddaf222e8ce3e8c81e8cdf861679abb05: Pulling from azureml/base
Digest: sha256:a1b514f3ba884b9a7695cbba5638933ddaf222e8ce3e8c81e8cdf861679abb05
Status: Downloaded newer image for mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/base:intelmpi2018.3-ubuntu16.04@sha256:a1b514f3ba884b9a7695cbba5638933ddaf222e8ce3e8c81e8cdf861679abb05
 ---> 93a72e6bd1ce
Step 2/15 : USER root
 ---> Running in 393b73df59b3
Removing intermediate container 393b73df59b3
 ---> 619a597fef9a
Step 3/15 : RUN mkdir -p $HOME/.cache
 ---> Running in af82045a0728
Removing intermediate container af82045a0728
 ---> 92c4cea30c0d
Step 4/15 : WORKDIR /
 ---> Running in fcccebaec30a
Removing intermediate container fcccebaec30a
 ---> 74738143ed62
Step 5/15 : COPY azureml-environment-setup/99brokenproxy /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/
 ---> d797c565fcc0
Step 6/15 : RUN if dpkg --compare-versions `conda --version | grep -oE '[^ ]+$'` lt 4.4.11; then conda install conda==4.4.11; fi
 ---> Running in ff03efcc360d
Removing intermediate container ff03efcc360d
 ---> e87c005b23e5
Step 7/15 : COPY azureml-environment-setup/mutated_conda_dependencies.yml azureml-environment-setup/mutated_conda_dependencies.yml
 ---> 97c2a118668f
Step 8/15 : RUN ldconfig /usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs && conda env create -p /azureml-envs/azureml_f7bdb7945ed8606d963cd2fc691ee724 -f azureml-environment-setup/mutated_conda_dependencies.yml && rm -rf "$HOME/.cache/pip" && conda clean -aqy && CONDA_ROOT_DIR=$(conda info --root) && rm -rf "$CONDA_ROOT_DIR/pkgs" && find "$CONDA_ROOT_DIR" -type d -name __pycache__ -exec rm -rf {} + && ldconfig
 ---> Running in 46dcf190b7e8
Solving environment: ...working... 
Warning: 2 possible package resolutions (only showing differing packages):
  - conda-forge::_openmp_mutex-4.5-1_llvm, conda-forge::libopenblas-0.3.7-h5ec1e0e_7, conda-forge::llvm-openmp-9.0.1-hc9558a2_2
  - conda-forge::_openmp_mutex-4.5-0_gnu, conda-forge::libgomp-9.2.0-h24d8f2e_2, conda-forge::libopenblas-0.3.7-h5ec1e0e_6done
[91m
==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.5.11
  latest version: 4.8.2
Please update conda by running
    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda

wheel-0.34.2         | 24 KB     |            |   0% [0m[91m
wheel-0.34.2         | 24 KB     | ########## | 100% [0m[91m
libstdcxx-ng-9.2.0   | 4.5 MB    |            |   0% [0m[91m
libstdcxx-ng-9.2.0   | 4.5 MB    | ####8      |  49% [0m[91m
libstdcxx-ng-9.2.0   | 4.5 MB    | #######9   |  79% [0m[91m
libstdcxx-ng-9.2.0   | 4.5 MB    | #########8 |  99% [0m[91m
libstdcxx-ng-9.2.0   | 4.5 MB    | ########## | 100% [0m[91m
scipy-1.4.1          | 18.9 MB   |            |   0% [0m[91m
scipy-1.4.1          | 18.9 MB   | #3         |  14% [0m[91m
scipy-1.4.1          | 18.9 MB   | #####1     |  52% [0m[91m
scipy-1.4.1          | 18.9 MB   | #######5   |  75% [0m[91m
scipy-1.4.1          | 18.9 MB   | #########2 |  92% [0m[91m
scipy-1.4.1          | 18.9 MB   | ########## | 100% [0m[91m
libgfortran-ng-7.3.0 | 1.7 MB    |            |   0% [0m[91m
libgfortran-ng-7.3.0 | 1.7 MB    | #######8   |  78% [0m[91m
libgfortran-ng-7.3.0 | 1.7 MB    | #########8 |  99% [0m[91m
libgfortran-ng-7.3.0 | 1.7 MB    | ########## | 100% [0m[91m
_libgcc_mutex-0.1    | 3 KB      |            |   0% [0m[91m
_libgcc_mutex-0.1    | 3 KB      | ########## | 100% [0m[91m
openssl-1.0.2u       | 3.2 MB    |            |   0% [0m[91m
openssl-1.0.2u       | 3.2 MB    | #######6   |  76% [0m[91m
openssl-1.0.2u       | 3.2 MB    | #########2 |  93% [0m[91m
openssl-1.0.2u       | 3.2 MB    | ########## | 100% [0m[91m
llvm-openmp-9.0.1    | 782 KB    |            |   0% [0m[91m
llvm-openmp-9.0.1    | 782 KB    | ########6  |  86% [0m[91m
llvm-openmp-9.0.1    | 782 KB    | ########## | 100% [0m[91m
ncurses-5.9          | 1.1 MB    |            |   0% [0m[91m
ncurses-5.9          | 1.1 MB    | #######8   |  79% [0m[91m
ncurses-5.9          | 1.1 MB    | ########7  |  88% [0m[91m
ncurses-5.9          | 1.1 MB    | #########7 |  97% [0m[91m
ncurses-5.9          | 1.1 MB    | ########## | 100% [0m[91m
zlib-1.2.11          | 105 KB    |            |   0% [0m[91m
zlib-1.2.11          | 105 KB    | ########## | 100% [0m[91m
liblapack-3.8.0      | 10 KB     |            |   0% [0m[91m
liblapack-3.8.0      | 10 KB     | ########## | 100% [0m[91m
scikit-learn-0.22.1  | 7.1 MB    |            |   0% [0m[91m
scikit-learn-0.22.1  | 7.1 MB    | ####7      |  47% [0m[91m
scikit-learn-0.22.1  | 7.1 MB    | #######5   |  76% [0m[91m
scikit-learn-0.22.1  | 7.1 MB    | ########9  |  90% [0m[91m
scikit-learn-0.22.1  | 7.1 MB    | ########## | 100% [0m[91m
_openmp_mutex-4.5    | 5 KB      |            |   0% [0m[91m
_openmp_mutex-4.5    | 5 KB      | ########## | 100% [0m[91m
ca-certificates-2019 | 145 KB    |            |   0% [0m[91m
ca-certificates-2019 | 145 KB    | ########## | 100% [0m[91m
libgcc-ng-9.2.0      | 8.2 MB    |            |   0% [0m[91m
libgcc-ng-9.2.0      | 8.2 MB    | ####9      |  49% [0m[91m
libgcc-ng-9.2.0      | 8.2 MB    | #######7   |  77% [0m[91m
libgcc-ng-9.2.0      | 8.2 MB    | #########5 |  96% [0m[91m
libgcc-ng-9.2.0      | 8.2 MB    | ########## | 100% [0m[91m
libcblas-3.8.0       | 10 KB     |            |   0% [0m[91m
libcblas-3.8.0       | 10 KB     | ########## | 100% [0m[91m
setuptools-45.2.0    | 653 KB    |            |   0% [0m[91m
setuptools-45.2.0    | 653 KB    | ########4  |  85% [0m[91m
setuptools-45.2.0    | 653 KB    | ########## | 100% [0m[91m
certifi-2019.11.28   | 149 KB    |            |   0% [0m[91m
certifi-2019.11.28   | 149 KB    | ########## | 100% [0m[91m
libblas-3.8.0        | 10 KB     |            |   0% [0m[91m
libblas-3.8.0        | 10 KB     | ########## | 100% [0m[91m
libopenblas-0.3.7    | 7.6 MB    |            |   0% [0m[91m
libopenblas-0.3.7    | 7.6 MB    | ####3      |  44% [0m[91m
libopenblas-0.3.7    | 7.6 MB    | #######6   |  77% [0m[91m
libopenblas-0.3.7    | 7.6 MB    | #########3 |  94% [0m[91m
libopenblas-0.3.7    | 7.6 MB    | ########## | 100% [0m[91m
numpy-1.18.1         | 5.2 MB    |            |   0% [0m[91m
numpy-1.18.1         | 5.2 MB    | #######5   |  75% [0m[91m
numpy-1.18.1         | 5.2 MB    | #########7 |  98% [0m[91m
numpy-1.18.1         | 5.2 MB    | ########## | 100% [0m[91m
readline-6.2         | 713 KB    |            |   0% [0m[91m
readline-6.2         | 713 KB    | ########3  |  83% [0m[91m
readline-6.2         | 713 KB    | ########## | 100% [0m[91m
python-3.6.2         | 19.0 MB   |            |   0% [0m[91m
python-3.6.2         | 19.0 MB   | #5         |  15% [0m[91m
python-3.6.2         | 19.0 MB   | #####3     |  53% [0m[91m
python-3.6.2         | 19.0 MB   | #######5   |  75% [0m[91m
python-3.6.2         | 19.0 MB   | ########9  |  89% [0m[91m
python-3.6.2         | 19.0 MB   | #########8 |  99% [0m[91m
python-3.6.2         | 19.0 MB   | ########## | 100% [0m[91m
pip-20.0.2           | 1.0 MB    |            |   0% [0m[91m
pip-20.0.2           | 1.0 MB    | #######9   |  80% [0m[91m
pip-20.0.2           | 1.0 MB    | #########5 |  96% [0m[91m
pip-20.0.2           | 1.0 MB    | ########## | 100% [0m[91m
tk-8.5.19            | 1.9 MB    |            |   0% [0m[91m
tk-8.5.19            | 1.9 MB    | #######7   |  78% [0m[91m
tk-8.5.19            | 1.9 MB    | ########9  |  89% [0m[91m
tk-8.5.19            | 1.9 MB    | #########9 |  99% [0m[91m
tk-8.5.19            | 1.9 MB    | ########## | 100% [0m[91m
xz-5.2.4             | 366 KB    |            |   0% [0m[91m
xz-5.2.4             | 366 KB    | #########4 |  95% [0m[91m
xz-5.2.4             | 366 KB    | ########## | 100% [0m[91m
sqlite-3.13.0        | 4.9 MB    |            |   0% [0m[91m
sqlite-3.13.0        | 4.9 MB    | #######5   |  75% [0m[91m
sqlite-3.13.0        | 4.9 MB    | #########7 |  98% [0m[91m
sqlite-3.13.0        | 4.9 MB    | ########## | 100% [0m[91m
joblib-0.14.1        | 198 KB    |            |   0% [0m[91m
joblib-0.14.1        | 198 KB    | ########## | 100% [0m
Downloading and Extracting Packages
Preparing transaction: ...working... done
Verifying transaction: ...working... done
Executing transaction: ...working... 
done
[91mERROR: Invalid requirement: 'azureml-defaults 1.0.45' (from line 2 of /azureml-environment-setup/condaenv.07uqp7tw.requirements.txt)
[0m[91m
CondaValueError: pip returned an error
[0mThe command '/bin/sh -c ldconfig /usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs && conda env create -p /azureml-envs/azureml_f7bdb7945ed8606d963cd2fc691ee724 -f azureml-environment-setup/mutated_conda_dependencies.yml && rm -rf "$HOME/.cache/pip" && conda clean -aqy && CONDA_ROOT_DIR=$(conda info --root) && rm -rf "$CONDA_ROOT_DIR/pkgs" && find "$CONDA_ROOT_DIR" -type d -name __pycache__ -exec rm -rf {} + && ldconfig' returned a non-zero code: 1
2020/02/19 12:33:49 Container failed during run: acb_step_0. No retries remaining.
failed to run step ID: acb_step_0: exit status 1
Run ID: cj4 failed after 1m56s. Error: failed during run, err: exit status 1
```

Kindly please suggest me a best solution for this problem as I am facing this issue.

Regards,
-Ahmad

Comment: For a start, you should remove personal info from the output you have pasted into your question. The "more information about this error" line includes a direct link to the logs for your instance, which you should not be publicizing.

Comment: For seconds, if you follow the link I mentioned above, it will give you detailed logs from the build process. This log suggests the issue is related to building `psutil`

Comment: Thank you for your response greg_data, can you explqain exactly what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Ahmed I'm afraid I can't really work out what you'd have to change to make the build succeed. Suggest stripping your conda env file down to absolute minimum, then adding packages back one at a time and testing how far the build gets each time until you find which package is causing the issue